# Query to find folder path and leaf node ID

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have table as

[image]

I want to create SQl or Procedure to fetch values as below

```
 FolderPath          LeafFolderID 

 Dept/CSE/Cfolder     100
 Dept/Mech            10
 Team/HR              22
 Settlement           3
```

Please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: You need a recursive/hierarchical query.  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle version is  12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `connect by` does the job:

```
select folderid, ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(foldername, '/'), '/') path
  from t
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by folderparentid = to_char(prior folderid)
  start with folderparentid = 'Root'
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=367f2113e96c2d89d651ee927873da78)</sup>**